# Amend apache's 'index of /' default page

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'd like to add (automatically) some PHP code to the default Apache's page, which lists directory index.

I think `.htaccess` should allow to do this.

However, `php_value auto_prepend_file "full_path_to_the_include_directory/prepend.php"` seems not to be working.

Did anyone try doing this successfully?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  You're simply setting a variable which will pass to PHP.  Apache's default directory index has nothing to do with PHP.  That value is only going to be useful if you're actually making a php request to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You can't: the directory indexes are not generated using PHP, but [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html). You could either read from the documentation to what extent they can be customized, or create a PHP script (`index.php`) that replaces the automatic index page. Built-in function [`scandir()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) might help you with this, and there are also several existing PHP index projects.

Comment: HOWEVER, found ReadmeName option in mod_autoindex. This includes header (footer is also possible) in the standard indexing page. Trying this at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HeaderName` and `ReadmeName` directives to include an external file in the directory listing, and this can be a PHP file. `HeaderName` inserts the output *before* the directory listing and `ReadmeName` inserts the output *after* the directory listing.

For example:

```
HeaderName /include/header.php
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: Yes, I'm digging it already... Could you tell me WHERE should the file (header.php) must be located? I mean I hhave no /include directory.

Comment: You can put your include files anywhere you like (providing it is within the public HTML directory). It is a URI-path. If you prefix the path with a slash then it is relative to the document root, otherwise it is relative to the directory being indexed.